# Accessing Status Code in Django Template

Tags: python, django

I've rendered a response which calls the appropriate template. For the error template I wanted to display different sets of information based on the HTTP Status Code returned, but I'm having an issue discerning how to access the status code of the response. I use
`render_to_response(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))`

Comment: Which HTTP status codes are you handling?

Comment: HttpResponse objects have a  `HttpResponse.status_code` attribute, just in case you find it useful.

Comment: @alejoss I tried to access response.status_code in the template, but was returned nothing.

Comment: Why do you need it in the template. I believe you could access it in the view and then render a different template depending on the code. Correct me if I didn't understand your question.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is not possible to access the status code in the template because Django determines the status code in reference to the result of the rendering process. That means the template is rendered first and then e. g. if there was no error you got status code 200.

If just want to customize the templates of 403, 404 and 500 codes, you can use [customized error views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views) or just use the customized error templates (e. g. 404.html in a template dir).

Answer (score 0):

If there is an error while processing a request then Django will insert an `exception` variable into the context, which you can retrieve on the template:

```
<p>exception: {{ exception }}</p>
```

When the `exception` is, for example, a 404 the output would be `Http404`